# SQL loop won't print column names

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have several columns in my database and I would like to print out all the column names, i.e. the names of the people in the database.

I'm having trouble with selecting ONLY the column names, this piece of code will run the loop but only the $i will print, not the actual names of the columns. Any advice? Thanks

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM People");

    $i = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { 

              $name = $row['query'];


              if ($count > '1') {
            ?>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td><p><b><?php print( $name . "</p></td></tr>");
            $i = $i + 1;
            ?>
```

P.s.
I tried with: 
    select COLUMN_NAME from Names.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'Names' but this won't work either, it tells me: access denied, don't really know why

Comment: i.e. you want column names not value inside column

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to get column names for your table.

```
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM your-table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['Field']."<br>";
}
```

But, as you get access denied. It means you do not have privilege to access table metadata.

So you can use either,

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   if (empty($columns)) {
       $columns = array_keys($row);
       // Here $columns is array and it contains all column name
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM People";
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );?>
<table>
<?php
while($row = mysqlsi_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){ 
   ?>
      <tr>
         <td><p><?php print( $row->id );?></p></td>
         <td><p><?php print( $row->name );?></p></td>
         <td><p><?php print( $row->lastname );?></p></td>
      </tr>
   <?php
   } ?>
</table>
```

Assuming,your SQL table has these fields: `id`, `name`, `lastname`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your while loop you could use

```
foreach($row as $column => $value){
  printf("Column: %s  has value: %s\n", $column, $value);
}
```

As mysql_fetch_assoc returns an associative array so you want the key => value information.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_field_name function in php to get column name

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM People");

$i = 1; $j=0; // I have declared $j incrementor
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { 

          $name = $row['query'];

    $columnname = mysql_field_name($query, $j); // This gives the column name of table.
          if ($count > '1') {
        ?>
        <table>
        <tr>
         <td><?php echo $columnname; ?></td>
        <td><p><b><?php print( $name . "</p></td></tr>");
        $i = $i + 1;
    $j = $j + 1;
        ?>
```

Comment: @parixit , that worked thank you. If I wanted to print all column names apart from the first one (which is my ID one), how would I do that?

Comment: Just use variable $i which starts counting from 1 and which skip your first cloumn name